# Submit button -> run .php -> popup -> refresh part of page php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

On my page, I currently have a select form and attached submit button, which is generated dynamically based on the entries in my database.  Here is my outputted HTML

```
<div id="structures">
<h1>Build</h1>
<form name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST" onsubmit="buildForm();return false;">
    <select name="buildID" class="buildClass">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Build a Structure</option>
<option name='Town Center' value='1' data-icon='../img/structures/tc.png' data-html-text='Town Center<i>
    500 minutes<br>50000 gold</i>'>Town Center</option>
<option name='Barracks' value='2' data-icon='../img/structures/barracks.png' data-html-text='Barracks<i>
    25 minutes<br>1500 gold</i>'>Barracks</option>
<option name='Dragon Roost' value='3' data-icon='../img/structures/droost.png' data-html-text='Dragon Roost<i>
    200 minutes<br>5000 gold</i>'>Dragon Roost</option>
<option name='Mage Hall' value='4' data-icon='../img/structures/mage.png' data-html-text='Mage Hall<i>
    40 minutes<br>300 gold</i>'>Mage Hall</option>
<option name='Test Lab' value='6' data-icon='../img/structures/testlab.png' data-html-text='Test Lab<i>
    1 minutes<br>10 gold</i>'>Test Lab</option>
    </select>
    <div id="buildSubmit">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

While I am finally improving with PHP/mySQL and html/css, javascript still throws me for a loop.

When the user clicks "submit," I want a popup menu to appear, and I want to update the database based on the contents of a separate php file.  Afterwards, once they close out of the pop up, I want to refresh a specific area of the page. I am using codeigniter, so I load my models functions through that to populate the page.

I would love to put more code, though honestly, its such a mess and completely worthless that instead I thought I'd ask more for a healthy guideline as to what I would have to do to implement something like this.

Examples would be amazing, but I am just trying to wrap my head around what I actually need to do to make this work.

Comment: Concerning "I want a popup menu to appear, and I want to update the database based on the contents of a separate php file" - could you give more detail on this?  Do you mean you want to read the actual php file's contents based on a selection and then update your database with those contents?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.  Upon clicking "submit" I would like to execute a php file which alters the DB.  Then, a popup window would appear to confirm the change.  Upon exiting out of the popup, the contents of the page would "refresh".  I have been successful in opening a pop up window upon hitting "submit" but no further than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the steps I think you're trying to accomplish alongside info to perform those steps.  Please clarify if I'm not understanding correctly...

After clicking the submit button...

**Execute a php file which alters the DB**
To do this, since you're using jQuery, you could make an ajax call to your PHP file with appropriate params that are needed for the DB update.

For an example of jQuery, PHP and mysql together, see [Using JQuery AJAX and php to fetch data from a mysql database](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107).  Also see the jQuery documentation on it: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Popup window to confirm the change (using JavaScript)**

```
var answer = confirm("Do you want to change this?")
if (answer){
   // Possibly call another PHP ajax script to commit database changes...
}
else{
   // Rollback database changes and do some other processing...
}
```

**To reload the page (using JavaScript)**

```
window.location.reload();
```